# After .load(), $.each() isn't detecting content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I load some checkboxes, which are unchecked, into a div. Immediately after load, I want to check of of those checkboxes automatically.

Here is a part of the code:

```
$("#list-conc").load("/getSomething", afterLoad());

function afterLoad() {
    $.each($("#list-conc input"), function () { .. });
}
```

My problem is that, without any kind of delay/setTimeout, by the time I get to the `$.each`, the HTML still isn't fully rendered into `$("#list-conc")`, so it never enters the cycle.

I added some `setTimeout`s, and it works fine. However, it isn't a viable solution. What I wanted to know is if I can bind some kind of event that detects when the `#list-conc` is filled.

I tried this:

```
$('#list-conc').on("change", function(event) {
    alert("here it is");
});
```

But it never gets there. I tried with `on.change` as well.

Comment: Typo, it should be `.load("...", afterLoad);`

Comment: but the callback is called AFTER html insertion... what html are you returning?

Comment: @lujcon No, it's not called after HTML insertion because the function executes immediately; notice the `()` following the function name?

Comment: @ja͢ck we both are right ;) The jQuery's callback is executed after insertion but function `afterLoad` is executed before ajax call. The magic of `()`. In this case the callback is `undefined`. I just wanted to point that the jQuery behaves as expected. The only problem is with the source provided in question.

Comment: @lujcon In this case, `afterLoad` is the only callback function that's relevant to this question; whatever jQuery uses internally is an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your discussion is about, but I understood that I need to remove the () from the callback? Why is that? What if I needed the callback to have any input?